# How to Disable Triple press emergency call feature in samsung

Tags: samsung, buttons, emergency-calls

My Samsung M31s keeps calling emergency services 112 more than 30 times a day. How to disable triple press power button panic mode / emergency call option. I have changed the settings, I have uninstalled all the packages with com.sec.android.emergency using adb, still there is no use. Kindly suggest me a solution to stop this. My phone is running on android 11, and I am using Indian SIM.thank you.

Comment: Have you disabled Android Settings -> Safety & emergency -> Emergency SOS?

Comment: @Robert I checked on my Galaxy M12, Android 13, but that setting doesn't allow disabling/enabling the trigger. It's possible to change which number to call though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to disable power button triple tap emergency call feature?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203972/44325) (not sure if applicable to Samsung).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable power button triple tap emergency call feature?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203972/how-to-disable-power-button-triple-tap-emergency-call-feature)

Comment: @Robert I have disabled the settings but it is not working.. The phone keeps calling 112...Thank you for sparing your value time